# No. of ways to put 1's in exactly K cell of 2*N grid such that no two 1's cell share adjacent side

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Its not like coloring of 2*N grid with m colors. Here I need to calculate number of ways to put 1's in exactly K cell of 2*N grid such that no two cells containing share adjacent side.

Ex : for
n = 4 k = 3 -> 12

n = 4 k = 2 -> 18

My approach : I got the relation P(n,k) = P(n-2,k-1) + P(n-1,k-1) + P(n-1,k)

Can we obtain any formula for this relation ??

**Similar question has already answered but my question is bit different**.

How to reduce this relation in a formula ??

Comment: Shouldn't there be a factor $2$ before $P(n-2,k-1)$?

Comment: No , This relation is giving correct answer for any value of (n,k).

Comment: Oh, I see where I was wrong ..

Comment: does $2*N$ grid mean $2$ rows $N$ columns ?

Comment: yes,there will be two rows and N columns

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This has to be twice A104698(n,k).

Comment: For reference, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945440/number-of-ways-to-select-k-non-adjacent-boxes-in-a-2-times-n-board) is previous question about this, where the recursive formula is derived. The sequence is listed as [A035607](http://oeis.org/A035607) in OEIS, and there is an explicit formula there but it does contains a summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the relation between (n,k)

$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} 2\binom{k-1}{r}\binom{n+1+r-k}{k}$

This agrees with calculations for n=3,k=2 and n=5,k=3.