# Removal of K objects such that no two are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $2$ rows joined side-by-side with $n$ objects in each row. What is the number of ways to remove exactly $k$ objects such that no two vacant places, after removal, are adjacent to each other?

For example, when $n=4$, $k=2$, the answer is $18$, and when $n=5$, $k=3$ the answer is $38$.

I'm not able to get a formula to solve it for any value of $n,k$ ($k \leq 2n$)

[image: rows_of_cells]

Comment: We have seen this recently under different wording-coloring squares. You could search for it

Comment: @RossMillikan can you provide the link for "coloring squares", please

Comment: Could you tell me one more result.  I think I got the formula would want to test it out

Comment: for n=4,k=3 answer is 12 @SatishRamanathan

Comment: My formula is breaking down, Could you let me know one more test case?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan  
for all n=k, answer is 2 and for n=3,k=2 answer is 8

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945440/number-of-ways-to-select-k-non-adjacent-boxes-in-a-2-times-n-board) is one duplicate.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958960/no-of-ways-to-put-1s-in-exactly-k-cell-of-2n-grid-such-that-no-two-1s-cell-s) is another

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the link to the solution of above problem](http://oeis.org/A266213)